# Wireless not working on hp-mini with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm currently trying to get wireless working on a hp-mini which has a broadcomm chip.
I have tried several approaches found here and it looks like the interface is recognized, but still see no wireless networks in NetworkManager, nor can I activate wireless in systemsettings.
The output from 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108
can be seen here:
http://goo.gl/L6OhLp
maybe anyone here has a clue what is wrong/how to fix this ?

Comment: Have you refered to [ubuntu's help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx) ? also , there's `firmware-b43-installer` package, which might be useful. There's also `bcmwl-kernel-source` package. Try `sudo apt-get firmware-b43-installer` first and let us know if that helps.

Comment: thanks for suggestions, Serg, I already had bcmwl-kernel-source installed, which recognized my wlan hardware. It was just not activated - had to reset bios config and remove/re-attach the batterie, as suggested elsewhere. after that, wlan indicator light went from amber to blue and everything worked - problem solved :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: Have a look at the excellent (though a bit long) answer above.  If you still have troubles with Broadcom drivers after that, drop me a note @Fabby below...

Comment: @Serg: have a look as well.  Broadcom drivers are notoriously difficult to set up, as they consist of a DSP with different firmware for each new adapter that comes out.  First ting to do is to send users over there...  Most of the time when it doesn't work, it's a new adapter and new code needs to be written...  :-(

Comment: @Fabby yeah,  I've heard that broadcom cards are pain in the rear area. I'm almost happy I've got realtek on my laptop - didn't have to through all the pains

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is marked as solved, but no solution is given.

Comment: I was unable to get my HP mini wireless to work with Ubuntu 15 or 16. Instead I plugged in a Netgear Wireless-N USB Adapter and it worked instantly.
Mine is an older unit, the WN111v2.

Answer (score 1):

Try the switch on the front of the computer on the right side
[image]

Comment: switch didn't work - had to reset the whole thing in bios/battery - see 1st answer. thanks for reply.